# Can't find and click on a dynamic element with RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm using RSelenium to click on a dynamic element after a search on this webpage: http://www.in.gov.br/web/guest/inicio.

Every time I search for a word, I would like to find the words/link ***'Ministério Da Educação'*** (it is the portuguese equivalent for Ministry of Education) on the right side of the results webpage and click on it.

[image]

I have used the *inspect element* feature from Google Chrome, but I am not having any success on finding and clicking that element. I have already tried using xpath, css selector, id ...

[image]

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
## search parameters 
string_search <- "contrato"
date_search <- format(
  as.Date("17/04/2019", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
  "%d/%m/%Y") #brazilian format

## start Selenium driver
library(RSelenium)
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(
  jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.firefox.verboseLogging=true"), 
  retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE) # for windows
# system(selCommand) # for Linux
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

## navigation & search
remDr$navigate("http://www.in.gov.br/web/guest/inicio")
Sys.sleep(5)

# from date
datefromkey<-remDr$findElement(using = 'css', "#calendario_advanced_from")
datefromkey$clickElement()
datefromkey$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "enter"))
datefromkey$clearElement()
datefromkey$sendKeysToElement(list(date_search))
datefromkey$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "enter"))

# to date
datetokey<-remDr$findElement(using = 'css', "#calendario_advanced_to")
datetokey$clickElement()
datetokey$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "enter"))
datetokey$clearElement()
datetokey$sendKeysToElement(list(date_search))
datetokey$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "enter"))

# string to search
wordkey<-remDr$findElement(using = 'css', "#input-advanced_search")
wordkey$sendKeysToElement(list('"', string_search, '"'))

# click search button
press_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'class', "btn")
press_button$clickElement()
```

**Here is where I struggle:**

1) first attempt: using a broader tag

```
# using a broader tag
categorykey <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', '_3_facetNavigation')
categorykey$getElementText()
```

With `getElementText()` I see that "Ministério da Educação" is there, but I do not know how to click on the link.

2) second attempt: using the xpath

```
categorykey <- remDr$findElement('xpath', '//li 
[@id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1555545676970_404"]/text()')
```

It returns an error. Selenium can't locate the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself after watching this video on YouTube:
[How to locate Dynamic Elements in Selenium Webdriver - XPATH Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQgA2Xqq6hI)

The code would be like this:

```
categorykey <-remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[contains(@data-value,"ministério da 
educação")]')

categorykey$getElementText()
# just to see if it's right

categorykey$clickElement()
```